# Replicating a clip path with polygons

Tags: html, svg, polygon

So I am trying to replicate the following screenshot:

[image]

Which is easy enough with pure css. Took 3 seconds.

But I need to support IE9, which is does not support `clip-path`. The only alternative I can find to have a div that scales properly is using SVGs.

The page will never have to scroll, so my plan is to have an absolute positioned div containing the svg and layering content over that. 
Here is where the issue lies, currently my code produces this:

[image]

Help?

Here is the underlying code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Error 404</title>

    <style>
 
        body {
            background: #F1F1F1;
            background-image: url('https://wallpaperclicker.com/storage/wallpaper/High-Definition-Ultra-HD-Wallpaper-96262544.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
        }

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
        }

         .main-bg {
           height: 100%;
           width: 100%;
        }

        .main-container {
            height: 100%;
            width: 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <svg class='main-bg' viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 55,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(41, 49, 56, 0.95);" />
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspect ratio of your viewBox does not match the container so you get gaps. You can use preserveAspectRatio="none" to allow the aspect ratio to vary with the container shape.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Error 404</title>

    <style>
 
        body {
            background: #F1F1F1;
            background-image: url('https://wallpaperclicker.com/storage/wallpaper/High-Definition-Ultra-HD-Wallpaper-96262544.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
        }

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
        }

         .main-bg {
           height: 100%;
           width: 100%;
        }

        .main-container {
            height: 100%;
            width: 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-container">
    <svg class='main-bg' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon points="0,0 0,100 55,100 100,0" style="fill: rgba(41, 49, 56, 0.95);" />
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I was unaware of the aspect ratio affecting polygons and the tag to disable that behaviour.